# Sync files between loacl folder and remote server using sync framework and wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a system which needs to sync images with a website and my local machine. After google I have found the best way is use microsoft synchonization framework. It is greatly support sync files between same machine or within same network.

But my requirement is sync with internet location. I found this article describe a scenario remote file sync. [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee819079%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) And they have provided a sample code as well. [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sync101-with-Remote-Change-e1877a3a). But that code only generated a.metadata, a.replicaid and a.store files in location. Can some one figure me out how to use this code. I want to enter "F:\Images" and mysite.com/images to local and remote.