# How to Synchronize Images Between Server and Windows 8 Mobile App Using WCF?

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-8

I'm Working on a Mobile Application which uses a WCF Web Service to Retrieve data from a Remote the Database. Currently images related to app are added to mobile app resource folder manually.

The requirement is to sync this Server Remote Folder and Mobile App resources folder periodically and download the images which are newly added in remote Server Folder.

Can anybody please tell , what is the best approach to  achieve this ?

I have tried solutions in [this Google Result](https://www.google.lk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=image%20sync%20wcf) , but they seems not what I'm looking for

Comment: App Preview : http://oi59.tinypic.com/iqzax1.jpg

Comment: Similar question is asked in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638174/sync-files-between-loacl-folder-and-remote-server-using-sync-framework-and-wcf